# Errors after removing Obj-C Bridging Header from Swift 2 Project

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, swift2, xcode7

Was trying to implement some Obj-C code into my Swift 2 project and decided that I was going to try a different method.

I deleted the files I added, including the newly created bridging header.

I went to build settings and removed the contents of the "Objective-C Bridging Header" setting and now I am getting bombarded with errors.

My project was running fine with no errors prior to the Obj-C fiasco.

Can someone help? See attached image for the errors I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Well i suppose you have objective C code which you are using in the swift files , but swift as such doesn't know about that code without the bridging header .All you need to do is create a bridging header again and put import statements in there for the objective C files you are using

Comment: I figured it out, somehow......I am using Cocoapods and tried just reinstalling the podfile with no luck. I closed out of xcode and installed the podfile again. When I opened xcode back up it seemed as if a few of the errors had disappeared but for some reason a good chunk of my code had been changed? I went back through and was able to fix all of the errors and compile the project finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the errors, your swift files (profileVeedVC.swift) still refer to the obj-c code. Remove the pod from your podfile and remove any references within the files.

Good luck!

Comment: I do believe I did something similar. I closed out of xcode, opened CoacoaPods and reinstalled the pod file. I then went back in and fixed any remaining errors and got it to work again! Was actually a great learning experience.